# querying remote mysql database from java application

Tags: java, mysql, database, spring-data-jpa

I want to be able to able to get a connection to a remote mysql database from a hava application. That is suppose i have a database server in london with user table, and another database server in paris with a product table and i want to be able from anywhere to get connection to these 2 databases and perform operations on them separately from a java application. My hope is to hide details such as ip address where the servers are located. I just want a kind of handle that abstract the lower level details for each of the servers and using this handle get a connection in a java application. Any help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think that this works for me, if it is what you are searching for:

```
    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + host + "/" + database, username, password);
        Statement stm = connection.createStatement();
        stm.execute("SOME PIECE of SQL CODE HERE");
    } catch (SQLException e) {

    }
```

Talking about address and that kind of stuff, if just you will have acess to the application, there's no problem to have your mysql data in the code. But if you will send this code for another people, you might need to create a client/server based application to avoid losing your credentials.